# What is the minimum setup to see the effect of mainAxisSize?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter and want to understand how `mainAxisSize` affects the visual arrangement of `MyBox`. I attempted to see the difference between `MainAxisSize.min` and `MainAxisSize.max`, but I did not find any difference. It might be because of my improper code below.

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Hello World'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 400,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: List.generate(3, (i) => const MyBox())),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBox();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Question

Could you tell me the minimum code to see the effect of `mainAxisSize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

play with min and max in this code to knows diffrent :

```dart
MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List.generate(3, (i) => const MyBox())),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```